# Underclocking to the speed of a 386?

Tags: underclock

Recently I acquired a couple of old Motorola two-way radios and discovered that a multitude of Moto aficionados have bricked their radios attempting to programme them with machines with 400 MHz Celerons. I've got an old Win98 box running with the same chip and they unanimously advise to **never** try to programme these radios with anything more than a 386. Would it be possible to underclock my Celeron down to these speeds?

Comment: I think the reference wants to say not to program the Motorolas with more than 386Mhz (that means them not communicating at more than that). The device you do it from should not be relevant.